# Return multiple choice column value from SO in Powerapps label with Lookup

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I have a powerapps app with a SharePoint Online list set up as a data source.
In one of my comboboxes users specify an item name which can be used as a lookup reference to find the correct record in the list.
Im trying to look up the relevant record in the list using their selection, and return the value/s of a column in that list which is set up as a choice column allowing multiple slections.

Previously, i have successfully used a standard lookup formula to retrieve values from single choice columns of a specific record; however im really struggling to get this to work when the column to be returned allows multiple choices.

Research points to using the ConCat function to list the values, but i cant get that to work either as i cant find a way to combine it with a lookup to list the values of a specific record. Every example of using ConCat specifies ThisItem, but there isnt a current item from that data set loaded into my app, i want to specify/lookup a specific item.

Any help appreciated, as this is now pissing me off.

Thanks

Comment: So your SP column is a choice field with multi-select? And you're trying to filter or return items in the list with user specified values from this column with multiple values?

Comment: The column I wish to return is a multi-select person type, though the value chosen & used to find the record is a single line text.
My list is a list of data sets, each of which has one or more owners selected in a multi-choice person field when the record is created. Eg. Customer Data set could be owned by Al & Bob.
In my user form, say users pick Customer from data sets list; I need my label to lookup up "Customer" in list and return "Al & Bob" as owners.
Standard lookup works fine on Data Centre, a choice field with 'Allow multiple choices' disabled.
Collection maybe the way to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I've understood your scenario completely, but here I'm able to concatenate the multi-choice people field's display names based inside a LookUp().

```
Concat(LookUp('Stack Test', ComboBox3.Selected.Title = Title).MultiPeople, DisplayName, "; ")
```

"MultiPeople" is the name of my SP list person column, with multi-select enabled.

[image]

Comment: With a little adaptation, i managed to get this to work, so thank you!
I had tried nesting a lookup within a Concat previously, but it never occurred to me to use a lookup that didn't specify the column to be returned in the third part of it.
Think you might have saved me quite a lot of time messing around with collections on the OnChange property of the combobox, so thanks again :)

Comment: Nice! Glad I was able to help, good luck with the rest of your app! Don't hesitate to ask other questions as they come along : )